# How to specify a runnable jar to use tomcat's lib for dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have made a java project in eclipse that's a runnable jar if I export it.

My structure of my project :

[image]

When I export my project as a runnable jar it asks me how I would like my dependencies to be packaged and I choose to put it in a lib folder. So when exporting it exports the runnable jar as well as creates a sub folder with my dependent jar files which I want to be only the 5 jars located in Referenced libraries.

This is the export window :

[image]

This creates my runnable jar and then a folder _lib with my other jars.

[image]

This works fine but as you see in the first image I also included the Tomcat lib library because some of the jar files in tomcat lib are used by my project.

The problem is that when I export, all the jar files in the tomcat lib get exported to my sub lib folder which I do not want.

Basically I want to deploy my runnable to a server witch will get the dependent jar files from the sub directory lib only those 5 jar files in image (Referenced Libraries). Tomcat is installed on the server so it should point to tomcats lib to get the rest of the jars.

Want my project to use the generated lib folder and then the tomcat lib.

Hope it makes sense what I am trying to ask.

Using Eclipse and java 1.7. developing on windows, deploying to linux running the application via command line on linux box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done to get this working is on the linux side to start the java runable class another way by specifying the classpath this will give the class you are trying to run the ability to first check the folders that you specify. So in my example instead of executing my app on the linux box with the following :

```
nohup java -jar /usr/local/P6/StockListShunter/StockListShunter.jar &
```

I did the following and specified the Class path lib that java should check for .jar file dependencies :

```
nohup java -classpath :/usr/mylib1/*:/usr/StockListShunter_lib/*:/usr/share/lib/*:  stockListShunter.Shunter &
```

Notice I specified 3 libraries java should check when running my runable class, mylib1,StockListShunter_lib and lib.

After you specified the classpath you will see you need to specify your java class witch will be your main method class. In my example it is `stockListShunter.Shunter` where stockListShunter is my package name.

Just take note that you should make sure that the class you are trying to excecute is included in one of the jar files that you specified in the classpath otherwise it wont find the class and you will get an error : `Error: Could not find or load main class stockListShunter.Shunter`

So when you run the command the process will be started, my program is in a loop so the process will be alive until I kill it. If your program should be alive you can confirm it is running by running the following command.

```
ps aux | grep stockListShunter.Shunter
```

Where `stockListShunter.Shunter` is your main class name. This should display all the processes where the command has a stockListShunter.Shunter in it.

If you want to end the process like mine that's in a loop you can run the following command.

```
pkill -f 'java.*stockListShunter.Shunter'
```

Again where `stockListShunter.Shunter` is your main class name. This should kill your java process.

Hope this could help some one in the future.